# android fetch data from sqlite and appened in string

Tags: android

I am fetching values from device database which are inserted previously, Please check the code below:

```
void initilizer(){          
        profile = new MySQLiteOpenHelper(this,DATABASE_NAME,null,1).getReadableDatabase();

        cur = profile.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{COL_NAME,COL_FLOOR,COL_AREA,COL_LAT,COL_LONG,COL_PHOTO}, null, null, null, null,null);

        candidates = new ArrayList<Candidate>();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value="+candidates.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        if(cur!=null){              
                if(!cur.isAfterLast())
                cur.moveToFirst();
            do{         
                candidates.add(new Candidate(cur.getString(0),cur.getInt(1),cur.getFloat(2),cur.getFloat(3),cur.getFloat(4),cur.getString(5)));
                cur.moveToNext();
            }while(!cur.isAfterLast());
            cur.close();    
        }

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "value="+candidates.size(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I am getting length as 6 in my toast. I need to get all the values and append it into a String and toast that string to see output. How can I do that? I tried "candidates.get(pos).getName()". But not working. Please help me.

Comment: please explain what exactly is your problem..

Comment: you are creating a new arraylist in loop, so it will replace your previous arraylist.

Comment: What do you mean by "all the values"? Do you mean the name, floor, area... for each candidate? Or do you mean the names of all of the candidates? You can do that in the loop. If you want to do it after the loop, you need to post your Candidate class.